# Validation in pydantic

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

I have written few classes for my data parsing. Data is the dict with very big depth and lots of string values (numbers, dates, bools) are all strings. With data which is presented there is no problems and type conversion works well. But with "empty" values ("" ones) I get validation error. I was trying to write validator but unsuccessfully. How should I realize that?

```
class Amount(BaseModel):

    amt: float = 0
    cur: int = 0

    @validator("amt", "cur")
    def check_str(cls, x):
        if x == "": 
            return 0
        else: 
            return x

d = Amount.parse_obj({"amt": "", "cur": ""})
```

```
2 validation errors for Amount
amt
  value is not a valid float (type=type_error.float)
cur
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

P.S. writing `try-except` construction in main body is no use, because `Amount` class is only a little subclass of much greater construction

Comment: Use `amt: Optional[float]` and use `None` instead of `""`? Same goes for `cur`

Comment: @DeepSpace, Unfortunately, using `""` is not my idea.  This value is produced by the program whose xml-request I'm parsing. To use `None` instead I must to change ALL empty values in  my monstrous construction (dict of dicts of dicts of dicts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `pre=True` to your validator:

```py
class Amount(BaseModel):

    amt: float = 0
    cur: int = 0

    @validator("amt", "cur", pre=True)
    def check_str(cls, x):
        if x == "": 
            return 0
        else: 
            return x

d = Amount.parse_obj({"amt": "", "cur": ""})
```

### References

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators

Comment: Than you very much! I'm studying pedantic for the first day, so my problems are quite easy, but I don't know how to solve them)

Comment: The docs at that point are less than clear: I didn't actually realise that the default validator ran first until I tried it.